# Determine whether each value in the array type field contains a keyword or not

Tags: solr

For example, I have the following two docs, and they look like this:

```
<result name="response" numFound="2" start="0" maxScore="9.075364" numFoundExact="true">
<doc>
  <arr name="author_affiliation">
    <str>Serviço de Imunologia, Hospital Universitário Prof. Edgard Santos, Universidade Federal da Bahia, Salvador, BA, Brazil</str>
    <str>Serviço de Imunologia, Hospital Universitário Prof. Edgard Santos, Universidade Federal da Bahia, Salvador, BA, Brazil</str>
    <str>Serviço de Imunologia, Hospital Universitário Prof. Edgard Santos, Universidade Federal da Bahia, Salvador, BA, Brazil</str>
    <str>Serviço de Imunologia, Hospital Universitário Prof. Edgard Santos, Universidade Federal da Bahia, Salvador, BA, Brazil</str>
    <str>Serviço de Imunologia, Hospital Universitário Prof. Edgard Santos, Universidade Federal da Bahia, Salvador, BA, Brazil</str>
  </arr>
  <str name="id">33685520</str>
</doc>
<doc>
  <arr name="author_affiliation">
    <str>Department of Urology, Charité University Hospital CCM, Berlin, Germany</str>
    <str>Department of Nephrology, Charité University Hospital CCM, Berlin, Germany</str>
    <str>Department of Anesthesiology, University of Colorado Health Sciences Center, Denver, Colorado</str>
    <str>Department of Nephrology, Charité University Hospital CCM, Berlin, Germany</str>
    <str>Department of Nephrology, Charité University Hospital CCM, Berlin, Germany</str>
    <str>Department of Surgery, Division of Transplantation, University of California San Francisco, San Francisco, California</str>
    <str>Department of Nephrology, Charité University Hospital CCM, Berlin, Germany</str>
    <str>Department of Anesthesia and Perioperative Care, University of California San Francisco, San Francisco, California</str>
  </arr>
  <str name="id">33685595</str>
</doc>
</result>
```

I need the array type field to contain `Hospital` in every value. How do I search to filter out a second doc that does not have the “Hospital" keyword in every value of the `author_affiliation` field?

At the moment I can only do it in code, and I'm wondering if it's possible to do it directly through Solr

Comment: You'd do that when indexing (i.e. create a separate field that has all the terms that are common between all your submitted values), I'm not aware of any way to handle that while just querying.